# C# File and Directory iteration, possible to do both at one?

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

This might be a confusing question but I have written below a Directory crawler, that will start at a root crawler, find all unique directories and then find all files and count them and add up their file size.  However, the way I have it written requires going to the directory twice, one to find the directories and the next time to count the files.  If/how is it possible to get all the information once?

```
       Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        HashSet<string> DirectoryHolding = new HashSet<string>();
        DirectoryHolding.Add(rootDirectory);


        #region All Directory Region
        int DirectoryCount = 0;
        int DirectoryHop = 0;
        bool FindAllDirectoriesbool = true;
        while (FindAllDirectoriesbool == true)
        {
            string[] DirectoryHolder = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory);
            if (DirectoryHolder.Length == 0)
            {
                if (DirectoryHop >= DirectoryHolding.Count())
                {
                    FindAllDirectoriesbool = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    rootDirectory = DirectoryHolding.ElementAt(DirectoryHop);
                }
                DirectoryHop++;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string DH in DirectoryHolder)
                {
                    DirectoryHolding.Add(DH);
                }
                if (DirectoryHop > DirectoryHolding.Count())
                {
                    FindAllDirectoriesbool = false;
                }
                rootDirectory = DirectoryHolding.ElementAt(DirectoryHop);
                DirectoryHop++;

            }

        }
        DirectoryCount = DirectoryHop - 2;
        #endregion



        #region File Count and Size Region
        int FileCount = 0;
        long FileSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DirectoryHolding.Count ; i++)
        {
            string[] DirectoryInfo = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryHolding.ElementAt(i));
            for (int fi = 0; fi < DirectoryInfo.Length; fi++)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(DirectoryInfo[fi]);
                    FileCount++;
                    FileSize = FileSize + fInfo.Length;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

The stopwatch result for this is 1.38

```
int FileCount = 0;
        long FileSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DirectoryHolding.Count; i++)
        {
            var entries = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryHolding.ElementAt(i)).EnumerateFileSystemInfos();
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                if ((entry.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    DirectoryHolding.Add(entry.FullName);
                }
                else
                {
                    FileCount++;
                    FileSize = FileSize + new FileInfo(entry.FullName).Length;
                }
            }
        }
```

the stop watch for this method is 2.01,

this makes no sense to me.

```
 DirectoryInfo Dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory);
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = Dinfo.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            FileInfo[] finfo = Dinfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (FileInfo f in finfo)
            {
                FileSize = FileSize + f.Length;
            }
            FileCount = finfo.Length;
            DirectoryCount = directories.Length;
```

.26 seconds  i think this is the winner

Comment: Tip: You don't need to do this: `if (FindAllDirectoriesbool == true)` this will work correctly: `if (FindAllDirectoriesbool)`

Comment: Use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` or recursion.

Comment: @M.Babcock how would that speed this up, it's certainly not a foreach loop but isn't it the same speed?  I think network connectivity here is the bottleneck not so much the code

Comment: @M.Babcock I still have to do GetDirectories to know what directories are next

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383358.aspx):

```
var entries = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(rootDirectory);
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    if(File.Exists(entry))
    {
        //file
    }
    else
    {
        //directory
    }
}
```

Or alternatively [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383689.aspx) (this might be more performant since [`FileSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx) already has most of the info you need and you can skip the `File.Exists` check):

```
var entries = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory).EnumerateFileSystemInfos();
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    if ((entry.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
    {
        //direcotry
    }
    else
    {
        //file
    }
}
```

Comment: I can certainly modify the code here, but how does change the issue of still finding and sitting all the directories and then going back to those directories?  Not trying to be rude i just dont understand,  I have to find all "entries" before i can foreach them

Comment: believe it or not, that method is 30% slower than the both I have up top, posted method:stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes= 1.35 method mentioned above: = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes 1.88

Comment: How do you get the file size in the else statement?

Comment: I tested the second method, if i have to use FileInfo it takes about 1.7 is i dont have to use fileInfo it takes 10 seconds, so If i can get filesize without calling fileinfo again that would be awesome

Comment: You'd have to manually acquire it - more accurate information, but probably slower than going through `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` (can't beat cached info): `long fileSize = new FileInfo(entry.Name).Length;`

Comment: @Mike: Looking at your original code you do manually query for `FileInfo` right now - instead use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` or `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` which uses cached information so should be much faster

Comment: the last comment you had gave me the idea so you get the answer ty!

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to write a recursive method.  Here it is in pseudocode:

```
void ProcessDirectory(Dir directory)
{
    foreach (var file in directory.Files)
        ProcessFile(file);

    foreach (var child in directory.Subdirectories)
        ProcessDirectory(directory);
}
```

You can also reverse the order of the foreach loops.  For example, to calculate the total size of all files with a recursive method, you could do this:

```
int GetTotalFileSize(Dir directory)
{
    ulong result = 0UL;

    foreach (var child in directory.Subdirectories)
        result += GetTotalFileSize(directory);

    foreach (var file in directory.Files)
        result += file.Length;

    return result;
}
```